# error listing files in a folder using Boost

Tags: c++, boost, iterator

I'm starting to use Boost in my C++ programs, but I encounter an error (segmentation fault) using this code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include "tools.h"
#include "Cycle.h"
#include "Base.h"
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("/home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/");
    directory_iterator end_itr(p),end;

    cout << "path = " << p.string() << endl;
    cout << "end iterator = " << end_itr->path().string() << endl;

    // cycle through the directory
    for (directory_iterator my_itr(p); my_itr != end_itr; ++my_itr)
    {
        // If it's not a directory, list it. If you want to list directories too, just remove this check.

        cout << "path iterator : " << my_itr->path().string() << endl;

        cout << "is regular = " << is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) << endl;
        if (is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) ) {
        // assign current file name to current_file and echo it out to the console.
            string current_file = my_itr->path().string();
            cout << current_file << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have 2 files in the folder I use (config.txt and test.txt). The first file given by the iterator is text.txt but the is_regular_file function returns false, and incrementing the iterator in the for loop cause a Segmentation fault(core dumped).

Any idea on what's going on?

Result is :

```
path = /home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/
end iterator = /home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/text.txt
path iterator : /home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/test.txt
is regular = 0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Process returned 139 (0x8B)
```

2nd version of code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include "tools.h"
#include "Cycle.h"
#include "Base.h"
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("/home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases/");
    directory_iterator end_itr;

    cout << "path = " << p.string() << endl;
    cout << "end iterator = " << end_itr->path().string() << endl;

    // cycle through the directory
    for (directory_iterator my_itr(p); my_itr != end_itr; ++my_itr)
    {
        // If it's not a directory, list it. If you want to list directories too, just remove this check.

        cout << "path iterator : " << my_itr->path().string() << endl;

        cout << "is regular = " << is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) << endl;
        if (is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) ) {
        // assign current file name to current_file and echo it out to the console.
            string current_file = my_itr->path().string();
            cout << current_file << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where do you print e.g. `end loop itr`? If you post code and output, then please make sure the code is the one actually generating the output.

Comment: You should also run in a debugger to catch the crash in action, and see there in *your* code it happens.

Comment: right..."end loop itr" was a mistake from me! (from a previous computation).

Comment: The main question is : why does the is_regular_file function returns false after the iterator gave me a correct file path?

Comment: After using a debugger, I found what I already suspected : the error occurs using operator++ on the directory_iterator. Anyone knows why?

Comment: `end_itr` or `end`? Your loop should not run at all since the the iterator `my_itr` will be immediately equal to `end_itr` (being initialized the same).

Comment: I tried both, using :
    directory_iterator end_itr;
and
    directory_iterator end_itr(p),end;

same result!
(i tried the 2nd one when i only had one file in my folder)

Comment: (I edited my first message and included the 2nd version of the code I use)

Comment: I can't replicate the problem, not with the new code you show (after fixing the problem of dereferencing `end_itr`).

Answer (score 0):

You should *never* dereference the end iterator. Therefore your names are misguided as well.

```
for (directory_iterator my_itr(p), end_itr; my_itr != end_itr; ++my_itr)
```

Here's a fixed - simplified - version:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/aa093eb1f9a9ca38)</kbd>**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p(".");

    cout << "path = " << p.string() << endl;

    // cycle through the directory
    for (directory_iterator my_itr(p), end_itr; my_itr != end_itr; ++my_itr)
    {
        // If it's not a directory, list it. If you want to list directories too, just remove this check.

        cout << "path iterator : " << my_itr->path().string() << endl;

        cout << "is regular = " << is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) << endl;
        if (is_regular_file(my_itr->path()) ) {
        // assign current file name to current_file and echo it out to the console.
            string current_file = my_itr->path().string();
            cout << current_file << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your advice,

unfortunately it doesn't solve my problem. It seems that calling the function is_regular_file causes the problem. (By the way, why is there a need to check if a file is "regular" if it has already be found by the iterator?).

Here is a code that causes the same error I have :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp>
#include <boost/iterator.hpp>

using namespace std;

using namespace boost::filesystem;

int main()
{
    path p("/home/malinou/workspace/grunbaum2/grunbaum/Bases");
    cout << "path = " << p.string() << endl;

    directory_iterator new_itr(p);  

    cout << "new_itr path : " << new_itr->path().string() << endl;

    if(is_regular_file(new_itr->path()))
       cout << "is regular" << endl;
    else
       cout << "is not regular" << endl;

    cout << "new_itr path : " << new_itr->path().string() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The last "cout" line is where the segmentation fault happens.

Comment: I don't know if it's usefull but i'm using CodeBlocks on Ubuntu, and added boost_system and boost_filesystem to my compiler(gcc) flags.

And my "Bases" folder is composed of 2 files : config.txt and test.txt.

Comment: Both files are not "regular" according to boost.